# sourcing a file inside a script

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, tcsh

I'd like to source a file inside a tcsh script. In code:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

unsetenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
source $1    
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH > temp_file
```

**The expected result:** The environment variable set by the script using the source command will be printed into a temporary file.

**Actual result:** The sourced file runs nicely, but the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable remains empty.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

---

**P.S.** `tcsh` is of course not my shell of choice, but I have a script at work that sets up numerous environment variables in `tcsh` that I want to get working in `bash`. I figured the easiest way (other than rewriting the `tcsh` shell every time) is to source it, print out the variables into a file, and with a bit of shell magic, re-source everthing back in bash.

Comment: If you run `env` before and after `source`, does *anything* change? If not, try the same *inside* the sourced script. That might give some clues.

Comment: I just tried it; it works for me the way you were expecting. Are you sure your sourced script is setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? You can add a line at the very end (or anywhere the script might exit) that `echo`s it to a different temp file.

Comment: Post the sourced script (preferably shrunk to a small example that exhibits the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further reference, this does indeed work, but one should not use the shebang to the tcsh path:

```
 #!/bin/tcsh
```

but rather use the path to 'env':

```
 #!/usr/bin/env tcsh
```

to allow flexibility on systems with tcsh installed in different paths.  For example, if 'tcsh' is installed in '/usr/bin/tcsh' then the former will fail, while the latter will still work.

Comment: Please elaborate. Why did this help?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with csh on OpenBSD. I guess my example works also with tcsh.

File test.csh:

```
#!/bin/csh
source data.csh
echo $VARIABLE
```

File data.csh

```
#!/bin/csh
setenv VARIABLE 1234
```

Result:

```
$ csh test.csh
1234
```